# my face has different normal shader even every vertex on my normal connected

Tags: faces, normals

I made sure I have no overlapping vertices, flipped normals, or sharp edges. But every face on this model still has a different surface shader.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's strange - if you _shade smooth_ then _shade flat_ again,  it seems to behave normally.

Comment: the reason why my model looks like this cause i used dissolved edge on some edge line.

Comment: I think you have split normals. Go to Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split normals

Comment: thanks a lot man, it solved

Answer (score 3):

I think you have [`Split Normals`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#custom-split-normals). Go to *Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split normals*